# Firestore rules to access collection that matches Auth uid

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am attempting to set up my security rules so that users can have full access to one specific document(named after their UID) and all subdocuments within this 'parent' document.

I have created the below rule to do so, however I am getting the error 'The caller does not have permission' when I attempt to read/write to the subdocuments or the parent.

I though the wildcard syntax would have me covered here. There's clearly a gap in my understanding.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /User/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == document
    }
  }
}
```

##### DB layout

**User**

- uid1

  - randomDocumentName
  - randomDocumentName
- uid2

  - randomDocumentName
  - randomDocumentName
- uid3

  - randomDocumentName
  - randomDocumentName

##### Code that interfaces with backend

```
db.collection("User")
   .doc(uid1) //this is set as a prop via auth UID of user, parent
   .collection(randomDocumentName) // this is the child document
   .add({
         name:'test'
       })
```

Comment: Rules don't do anything on their own. Please edit your question to also include the minimum code with which you can reproduce that error. In that code be sure to log any values that make it clear that the conditions of your rules are met (i.e.: log the UID of the user, and the path you are writing to).

Comment: What's "randomDocumentName" in the collection method? It seems you are trying write rules for a subcollection. What is its name? Or is it variable?

Comment: it's called members currently, I plan to add more of these subcollections such as a config, images, etc. Hence I put random name.

It is a subcollection of the UID document. I currently have other documents inside 'members' that I want to be subject to these rules.

I.e allow access to uid document and all sub collections if auth uid matches parent collection name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem after using the rules playground.

First I didn't have permission to look at the parent document at all, then I gave specific document permission to each user to access the specific child document.
If I add a new child document I will need to add a rule.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /UserData/{ID}{
    allow read, write :if request.auth  != null && request.auth.uid == ID;
    // allow users to create and access their parent document
    }
  
    match /UserData/{userId}/randomDocumentName/{doc=**} {
      allow read, write :if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId; // allow read and write to the documents they own
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How is that `randomDocumentName` generated ?

Comment: I initialize it in a batch write the first time a uid is authorized. I hard code `randomDocumentName` as `members` to the path User/[UID]/randomDocumentName .

Comment: This is a bit confusing, `randomDocumentName` is a collection

Answer (score 1):

This might work

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /User/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: no dice with this fix, ill wait and see if it still needs to propagate but I doubt that's the issue

Comment: @AWebster make sure the collection name is exactly the same in rules as well.